# firebase-tools error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: unix, firebase, npm, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to deploy Firebase hosting of my web app.

At the command line, when I type `firebase deploy`, I get the following error.

Note: `firebase deploy` is just one example. The same error occurs for all `firebase` commands. (e.g., `firebase --help`, `firebase -v`, `firebase login`, `firebase logout`, etc.)

Error

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
>                   throw err;
>                   ^
>
> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/mowzer/.config/configstore/update-notifier-firebase-tools.json'
>   You don't have access to this file.
>
> at Error (native)
>   
>     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
>   
>     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
>   
>     at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
>   
>     at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
>   
>     at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:34:17)
>   
>     at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:123:23)
>   
>     at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase:5:48)
>   
>     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>   
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

Everything I have tried so far (including every CLI `firebase` instruction) rejects me for lack of access.

What can I do? What should I try?

*(I am on a Mac OSX Yosemite v10.10.5 and firebase-tools v3.0.3)*

Edit: When I do `sudo firebase deploy`, I get the following error.

> Error: The entered credentials were incorrect.

### I tried the following solution.

I tried to delete problem files then reinstall `firebase-tools`.

Terminal.sh

```
cd
cd .config/configstore
# Delete problematic files
rm firebase-tools.json
override rw-------  root/staff for firebase-tools.json? y
rm update-notifier-firebase-tools.json
override rw-------  root/staff for update-notifier-firebase-tools.json? y
# Reinstall firebase-tools
cd
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Then...

```
cd path/to/directory
cd firebase deploy
```

Now this file generates the error:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
>
> cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/configstore

Comment: It's banal, but...have you tried using sudo?

Comment: @DevidFarinelli: Yes. When I do `sudo firebase deploy` I get the following error: *Error: The entered credentials were incorrect.*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the permissions of modules you have npm installed. This is something lots of developers run into, and npm actually has [some documentation on how to resolve it](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions). Once you go through that, try again (you may need to re-install `firebase-tools`) and things should work.

Comment: Doing a "sudo npm install -g firebase-tools" fixes the issue (for me)

Comment: Using "sudo" does not fix anything. It will just execute npm as root, which is **absolutely not a fix**. Lots of project were broken because of npm being executed as root. The real solution is fixing the permission problems.

Comment: I ran the suggested permissions command 1. `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/<YOUR_USERNAME_HERE>/.config` 2. Then ran the bash command again without any permission errors `curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash` 3. Lastly ran the upgrade `curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`

Answer (score 35):

I fix it by adding `sudo` at the beginning of the command line!

Comment: Downvoted because using simply using `sudo` whenever something doesn't work is not just counterproductive but also dangerous to many systems.
Fixing wrongly set permissions will fix the problem of OP for real.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by using this command `curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`

Comment: I try this and works form me.

Comment: Make this the accepted answer. Works like a charm

Comment: Works like magic 

Comment: You saved my day, Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Add `sudo` prior to command it should work

```
sudo npm -g i firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by doing `chmod 755` on all the files in the `configstore` directory

Answer (score 1):

Expanding more detail to the solution provided by @jacobawenger:

[The most robust solution is to install Homebrew and let Homebrew manage the npm package installation for you](http://brew.sh).

Terminal.sh

```
# EACCESS error reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions
# Install Homebrew # Reference: brew.sh # Ensures NPM is installed properly to avoid EACCESS errors
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
# Install npm # Reference: brew.sh
brew install node
# Install firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools # Non-recurring task # Also updates to newest version (see notice)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Way:

Back up your computer.

if you have Permission issue run first this

```
 sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then 2nd

```
1)-  mkdir ~/.npm-global
2)-  npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
3)-  export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
4)-  source ~/.profile
5)-  npm install -g jshint
6)-  NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `--unsafe-perm` flag. Just like this:

```sh
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run the command as

> su root

if you are using ubuntu.
For me, just use sudo, did not work.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.x.x and I was trying install firebase through npm

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was basically reinstalling the node using the node version manager.
For this, you just [install latest node js version this way](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#nvm)

In my case at the point of this reply, the LTS Version of the Node JS is v14.17.0 hence `nvm use 14.17.0` now try re-running the build.

Comment: Thank you My Yash, for the correction. Apologies for the short hand writing.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue recently.
running this command solved the issue for me

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.config/configstore
```

Answer (score 0):

There's information explaining why the sudo command makes the difference, and generally, when we are calling commands in terminal mode, we are not recognised as the computer's administrator, whereas certain commands are reserved for the administrator only.  The sudo command enables terminal commands to be executed as the administrator.  You can read [about the sudo command](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/apd5b0b6259-a7d4-4435-947d-0dff528912ba/mac) here : )

Thank you for your contributions towards resolving this issue.