# Changing target Firebase ID using firebase-tools CLI

Tags: firebase, command-line-interface, firebase-tools

At the command line...

When I run `firebase deploy`, I get the following error:

> Error: The entered credentials were incorrect.

When I run `firebase deploy --debug`, [I get the following (more detailed) error (and log) shown when you click here](https://notehub.org/tilc6). ([firebase-debug.log](https://notehub.org/tilc6))

When I run `firebase deploy --project good-project-id`, I get the expected deployment behavior.

When I rerun `firebase deploy` and `firebase deploy --debug` I get the same errors already described.

How do I make the proper changes to eliminate the errors when running `firebase deploy`?

Notes:

- I am running Mac OS/X Yosemite v10.10.5
- [I just ran the NPM installation procedure (via Homebrew) described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38090392/1640892).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the contents of your `.firebaserc` file in your project directory. You likely have a "default" project alias specified. Run `firebase list` and see if that **project id** shows up there as well (note it should be the project id, not the instance/subdomain name).

If it doesn't match, that's likely your issue. Another thing you can try is deleting the `.firebaserc` file and then running `firebase use --add` to create a new project alias.

Comment: Hi Michael, I followed your steps to change the target project while deploying cron jobs. But it still showing me the old records. I have the editor permission in the project where I am trying to deploy the cron jobs. Do I need the owner permission for deploying the cron jobs ?